# cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

While creating an [ADO.NET Entity Data Model](https://blog.udemy.com/ado-net-entity-data-model/), following error occured:

> Error  66  Argument 10: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter' D:\Aziz\Aziz Project\Development\Running Development\Web\pos\pos\Model1.Context.cs  351 278 pos

How is it possible to solve this error?

Answer (score 45):

```
using System.Data.Object;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

> Replace for:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

Comment: Correct Answer, just adding that the replacement needs to be done in the .context.cs file

Comment: But what will happen if I update my model it come again same what to do for permanent solution?

Comment: This should be done in the .Context.tt file if using an edmx model, so future changes will re-generate the correct namespaces.

Answer (score 11):

This is one of most frequent compile-time errors you may face in the Entity Framework. This occcurs when a

1. Version conflict exists, or
2. Namespace is used.

By default, while compiling your project, the framework includes the namespace `using System.Data.Objects;`.

**Solution:**

To fix this issue:

- If the version conflicts, install the package for the respective version of the Entity Framework.
- If the version is the same, change the above namespace to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`.

Comment: Thanks. If my answer is useful to you please upvote and accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark nearer to the answer and up arrow button.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi BSG, how can I check installed version and respective version

Answer (score 0):

Expand your file yourmodel.edmx in visual studio

Edit the .tt files:

```
Replace: <#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
```

by

```
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
```

Save the changes in both files. Check if everything is ok.

If not, open your model and regenerate again..

It should works ok