# cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core

Tags: entity-framework

Whenever I update the EF 6 model from the database (adding a table), I get the error above.

This isn't a new problem.  I read all the suggestions spelled out here ([cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574298/cannot-convert-from-system-data-objects-objectparameter-to-system-data-entity)).

The answers say to replace

```
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

with

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

When I update the model from the database and compile, the offending name spaces (System.Data.Objects and System.Data.Objects.DataClasses) come right back, generating a compilation error, AND **the added table vanishes from the model!**

So I find myself caught in the vicious cycle of adding a table, get a compilation error, replace the aformentioned lines, and lose the table.  Rinse, repeat.  After 5-6 tries, the added table shows up in the model when I get lucky.

So I have tried reinstalling the Entity framework (6.2.0), but that does not make the problem go away.

Someone mentioned a "version conflict."  What is the way to check that other than uninstalling and reinstalling the package which I have already tried multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

Its been 3 month since you posted your question. Hope you resolved your issue by now. I just got the same problem and updating template file in entity framework solved the issue for me. Hope my answer will help anyone coming to this question!

To update template file:

1. Expand your EDMX file

2. Double click on `(YourModelName).Context.tt`

3. Find corresponding line in the file by pressing Ctrl + F and searching for `using System.Data.Objects`

4. Replace lines

```
  using System.Data.Objects;
  using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

with

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

5. Save the template file

From now on it should generate correct using statements every time you update entities (tables or stored procedures)